# Multiplying both sides by inverse when the operation is addition

Tags: group-theory

Consider group of integers $\mod 15$ under *addition*
$$\{0,1,2,\cdots 14\}$$

A line in a proof in my textbook is
$$gh_1=gh_2 \implies h_1=h_2 ~~(\color{grey}{\color{red}{\text{multiplying}} \text{ both sides on left by $g^{-1}$}})$$

This like freaks me out. Here is the reason why :
Inverse of $g$ is $15-g$. But how can I multiply this both sides when the operation known is just addition? I wonder what they  really mean is to *add* $(15-g+1)h_1$ both sides as this isolates $h_1$ on the left hand side... But this complicates the right hand side too much and I feel I'm not approaching this correctly. Any help ?

Comment: If you consider only the group under addition, then $gh_1=gh_2$ should also be intepreted as $g+h_1=g+h_2$ also.

Comment: Also, may I know what is the textbook that you found the text?

Comment: Wow then multiplying $g^{-1}$ both sides is just adding $g^{-1}$ and it isolates both $h_1$ and $h_2$ on both sides. I see my error. Thank you so much :) @AlanWang

Comment: @AlanWang I'm using Gallian. Now that I see again its completely my incorrect interpretation of the proof... This is a great textbook so far. Thanks again :)

Comment: @AlanWang If you aren't busy I'd love to mark it best answer if you write above comment as answer ?

Comment: Done. You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are considering the group under addition, then we should write $g+h_1=g+h_2$ rather than $gh_1=gh_2$. In this case, we add the additive inverse or negative of $g$, written as $-g$, on both side of equation to get $h_1=h_2$. This is also well known as the cancellation law in groups.